# ARC migration using Xcode does not remove release

Tags: objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I use the function Xcode provided to convert a MRC project to ARC. 
Edit -> Convert -> To Objective-C ARC. After check, it said "No source changes necessary". But after click update, I tried to build the app and received lot of errors. All of the errors are about release, autorelease. And I also notice the properties dose not change retain, assign to strong or weak. Should I change my code manually in order to convert to ARC or I miss some steps during migration?

Answer (score 0):

just add "-fno-objc-arc" in
BuildPhase -- >compile Source ---> double click the errored file ---> box will poped up --> paste the "- fno-objc-arc".

I hope it will work..

I have attached the image FYR [image]

Comment: I know I can set compile flag to use non-arc class in ARC, but that's not what I want. I do want to change the existing code base to arc

Comment: only add this "- fno-objc-arc". don't want to remove the release and autorelease